# Verify bcrypt in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

I have a problem with password verification when logging in. I get a "no comparison" back.  where am i getting the error?

additionally user.password is undefined

```
function post(req, res) {
    User.find({ email: req.body.email,
    password:req.body.password })
        .then(user => {
            if (user.length < 1) {
                res.status(400).json({
                    message: "Mail dosent exists"
                });
            } else {
                bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_ROUNDS, function (error, salt) {
                    console.log("salt: " + "" + salt)
                    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, (error, hash) => {
                        bcrypt.compare(user.password, hash)
                            .then(result => {
                                res.status(200).send(result)
                                console.log("logged")
                            })
                            .catch(error => res.status(500).send(error));
                        console.log("no comparison")
                        console.log("hash:" + "" + hash)
                        console.log("hasło:" + "" + user.password)


                    });
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: "*additionally user.password is undefined*" What did you expect otherwise...? Where have you defined `user`?

Comment: try `bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)` . Also please check what data elements are returning with `user` from database

Comment: I have an example for you of comparing this here https://github.com/tradecoder/hashing-password but not implemented to this project. you may check the comparing part from readme.md